# What WiFi-Direct Libraries Exist?

Tags: ios, linux, macos, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct

I want to play with screen sharing between my apple devices.  I know WiFi direct is part of what supports the Airdrop feature to send files between macs and want to play around with that API.

I'll keep on searching, but was wondering if anyone has done this before or if Apple won't let you touch that API.

I'd also be happy to hear about any libraries that may be available specifically for raspberry-pi or for Linux in general.

Thanks

Comment: AirDrop (file sharing) and AirPlay (audio / video remoting) are two totally different things. Which one are you interested in?

Answer (score 5):

A friend of mine demoed an Android project he was working on the other day that utilized the AllJoyn library. AllJoyn is an open source API that supports Wifi-direct as well as other wireless protocols and is supported on Android, Linux, and iOS. It might be worth looking in to.

https://www.alljoyn.org/

Comment: Do you know of any wrapper for it, or a lightweight version?